# How to apply a 2D image to a 3D Model which I can then use with Google Sceneform and ARCore?

Tags: image-processing, 3d, augmented-reality, arcore, sceneform

I'm looking for a guide on how to take a 2D image (Jpeg/PNG) and apply it to a 3D object template programmatically.

The specific use case I am trying to replicate is taking a picture and applying it to a 3D picture frame, similarly to how Cart Magician does (https://cartmagician.com/) where you can upload an image and then applies it to a picture frame object template that they provide which then renders the object with the image that can be viewed with Google AR.

Could anyone help or point me in the right direction?

Thanks in advance!

This is the AR frame with image, the image should be interchangeable.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a ViewRenderable surrounded by the 3D model of a painting frame. The ViewRenderable will have the 2D image put on it.